# How to loop through csv and be able to go back a step or proceed line by line?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I'm trying to look up a time for a user. Let's say they input 13(minutes), my code scrolls through the csv and finds each row that has 13 in the time column. It then prints out the row one at a time. I don't know how to allow a user to have the option of revisiting a previous step? My code currently just reverses the order of the csv, starts from the bottom, even if the rows are not the 13 minute- selected rows.

I'm a total newbie so please try to explain as simple as possible.. Thanks

Please see code:

```
def time():

while True:
    find = input("Please enter a time in minutes(rounded)\n"
                "> ")

    if len(find) < 1:
        continue
    else:
        break


print("Matches will appear below\n"
      "If no matches were made\n"
      "You will return back to the previous menu.\n"
      "")

count = -1

with open("work_log1.csv", 'r') as fp:
    reader = csv.DictReader(fp, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        count+=1
        if find == row["time"]:
            for key, value in row.items(): # This part iterates through csv dict with no problems
                print(key,':',value)

                changee = input("make change? ")
                if changee == "back":                    # ISSUE HERE******
                    for row in reversed(list(reader)):   # I'm trying to use this to reverse the order of whats been printed
                        for key, value in row.items():   # Unfortunately it doesnt start from the last item, it starts from
                            print(key,':',value)         # The bottom of the csv. Once I find out how to iterate through it
                                                         # Properly, then I can apply my changes
            make_change = input("make change?  or go back")

            if make_change == 'y':
                new_change = input("input new data: ")
                fp = pd.read_csv("work_log1.csv")
                fp.set_value(count, "time", new_change) # This part makes the changes to the row i'm currently on
                fp.to_csv("work_log1.csv", index=False)




        print("")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can always have list that keep last `n` lines so you can go back using this list, after reading new line just `history.pop(0)` and 'history.append(last_line)'

or alternatively you can wrap this logic using `stream.seek` function